# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' pervious asked a q before answer got this

Tags: python

```
currencies = {'yen': 0.0067, 'bsp': 1.35, 'usd': 0.65, 'ero': 0.85}

if choice == "2":
    Current_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
    amount = input("Type amount you wish to exchange")
    Future_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange into: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
    New_Amount = Future_Currency / Current_Currency * amount
```

honestly this is killing me i just need to get this fixed last hurdle that i cant get over i am a very big novice so please keep the language simple

Comment: What is the **input** you give when the program runs? What version of Python is this, 2 or 3?

Comment: Shouldn't one of the exchange rates be 1? bsp == 1??

Comment: @Jim - maybe its all relative to some [ideal currency](http://xkcd.com/512/)

Comment: Darn, I bet it all on cute kitten videos.

Answer (score 2):

Both Future_Currency and Current_Currency are strings, as input. It looks like what you want is to use them as keys to your dictionary of rates, as follows:

```
New_Amount = currencies[Future_Currency] / currencies[Current_Currency] * amount
```

Or, split up into more lines for readability:

```
Future_Value = currencies[Future_Currency]
Current_Value = currencies[Current_Currency]
ratio = Future_Value / Current_Value
New_Amount = ratio * amount
```

Comment: no need for `float` here ... The values in the dict are already floats.

Comment: Bingo. Was going to answer this myself but sadly the iPhone is an awful platform for answering SO questions :( +1

Comment: so if i copy in and swap this for the last line it should work

Comment: Fixed that, thanks. Yes, this should work, provided you give the proper input.

Comment: so do i just cop and paste this in or what else will i have to changed

Comment: If you replace your last line with either of those two things, it should work.